# Incorrect C# syntax highlighting with @"\"

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

The title really says it all, but when I use the @ character to ignore escapes in a string literal @"Like This\", the \" is interpreted as a quote character belonging to the string rather than the terminating quote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an issue with [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/), which Stack Overflow uses, and is not something the Stack Overflow team are likely to remedy.

That said, google-code-prettify is open-source - so feel free to go fix it!

Answer (score 0):

Testing

```
string test1 = @"Like This\";
string test2 = "Like This\\";
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox